# Can I submit a new subscriber to Campaign Monitor with an AJAX request?

Tags: shopify, campaign-monitor

I have a form on a Shopify site that has a name and email field as well as other fields. The form submits to a Shopify url. Before it submits, I want to send the name and email fields to a Campaign Monitor list.

Is this possible to do in JavaScript? Is there some way to use an AJAX request to add a subscriber to Campaign Monitor?

- I cannot find a Campaign Monitor JavaScript API.
- I have tried embedding a form generated by Campaign Monitor, and submitting it using jQuery.ajax(), but that encountered a CORS error indicating that Campaign Monitor will not accept the request.
- I cannot submit the embedded form directly in a way that will reload the page as I need to also submit the other form to Shopify.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a middleware accepting CORS requests that will receive subscriber data via AJAX from your Shopify website, process/validate it and then submit it to Campaign Monitor.

You can also avoid CORS by creating a [custom app](https://shopify.dev/concepts/apps#custom-apps) and adding a [proxy extension](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension) pointing to a specific path on your server. Then you can send AJAX requests to a path within the Shopify e.g. `/tools/campaign-monitor/subscribe` which will actually be proxied to your server script that will send subscriber to Campaign Monitor.

Comment: So either of these options require another server where I write a handler in some server-side language? (I don't have a problem with that, but I hoped that it could be avoided.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Campaign Monitor integration options but I believe that if you could not find its JavaScript API then yes, you would need to create a server-side script to do that.